# Changing PublishUrl property in csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, vsto, clickonce, target

I need to be able to change the PublishUrl property in my Excel VSTO project's csproj file in order to manage which publish url is used based on the configuration that is set in the configuration manager.  This needs to happen regardless of what the developer enters in the Publish Wizard or the project properties window.  I really need to control it at the point of publishing, based on the configuration set.  I have found no solutions that work and it seems that this would be more common than I am finding.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce-saurabh-bhatia/) will help you. You can create a small script to re-sign the files, and when you do that, you can set the URL. The article shows an example (but w/o the URL -- it's just another option available when using mage).